# Проблема обновления в линуксе

Tags: репозиторий, linux

Я неоднократно встречал в интернете вопросы по поводу решения проблемы обновлений из-за ,возможно, неправильно установленного репозитория.

**E: Неизвестный тип ««deb» в строке 1 в списке источников /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pantheon-debian.list**

**E: Не удалось прочитать перечень источников.**

Но ответов , которые бы решали проблему , я не встречал. Как решить подобную дилемму?

Внутри проблемного файла следующее :

```
"deb http://dl.bintray.com/mithrandirn/pantheon-debian/ jessie main"
```

Comment: Ну для начала хотя бы показать нам содержимое проблемного файла

Comment: deb http://dl.bintray.com/mithrandirn/pantheon-debian/ jessie main

Comment: Прям вот так с кавычками? Кавычки абсолютно точно не нужны

Comment: Теперь без них..

Comment: А без кавычек я не верю, что не работает, потому что без кавычек всё с файлом нормально

Comment: Он прям в ковычках стоит. Что вы предлагаете делать? Через VIM не редактируется

Comment: Что значит не редактируется?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85315/discussion-between-mickeyu-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моей ситуации мешали кавычки `" "` , стоило лишь запустить текстовый редактор из под **root** и убрать их. Сейчас все работает.